# What eloquent relations to use?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building my first Laravel application and I'm confused about the relations because there are so many relationships.

- A user can have multiple players(characters).
- Players can play on multiple servers.
- Each server has 2 stores(block store, perk store).
- Each block store uses a different currency on a different server.
- The perk store uses the same currency on all servers but some
  products can be bought with server-specific currency.
- Players also have a bank and a wallet that contains each currency
  that they own.
- Each server can have teams(guilds, factions, kingdoms) depending on the game type.

```
class CreateWalletTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('wallets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('player_id');
            $table->integer('currency_id');
            $table->decimal('amount');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('player_id')->references('id')->on('players');
            $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currencies');
        });
    }
}
class Wallet extends Model
{
    public function player(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class);
    }

    public function currency(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Currency::class);
    }
}
class CreateCurrenciesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('plural');
            $table->string('symbol');
            $table->integer('decimals');
            $table->boolean('tradable');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
class Currency extends Model
{
    public function wallet(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Wallet::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what part is confusing you. Is it the database design? The making of the models? The defining the relationships? Each of these could be a question on its own but most importantly you need to be explicit on what you've already done, what works and what is not working for you as well as sharing relevant code. Here for example you have parts of the database tables as well as some of the relationships but missing other tables and (mainly M-N) relationships. Keep in mind that questions here need to be short and very specific. This one looks a bit too broad asking too much

Comment: Sorry for that. I've updated my question. I'm new to all of this. I did some PHP 16 years ago. and went on to become an electrician. My brother was going to help me with this but bailed on me.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here. It's still quite broad as a question. Focus on a pair of models at a time and what kind relationships they have it should be ok. Just a few points: (1) if you have a many to many relationship like e.g. like you described player-server here, you need a separate "pivot" table to hold that relationship e.g. `player_server(player_id, server_id)` and need to use `belongsToMany` for both sides to describe this relationship. (2) models "belong to" a model if they have the foreign key on the table so wallet-belongs to-currency and currency-has many-wallets

Comment: Read through https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction carefully as well it should give you a good idea on how relationships work

Comment: I did read that before posting. It's just so much information that isn't directly relevant that it confuses me. I'm fairly good at picking up new things but normally I'm able to find more specific examples of what I'm doing so it makes more sense to me. That is how I learned C# and Java. That is why I tried to stay away from the pivot tables because that will double the number of tables to keep track of. Anyway, the currency table just holds the currency types and the properties of those currencies. So do you still think a wallet-belongs to-currency and currency-has many-wallets?

Comment: The way you have the table here, the wallet refers to a specific wallet belonging to a player. In that sense there can be many wallets that have the same currency in them (so currency has many wallets i.e. there are many rows in `wallets` withe same `currency_id`) on the other hand each wallet can only contain one currency.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Awesome. Thank you so much. For a moment there I thought you didn't get what I am trying to do but you did.